# Rails and understanding "belong_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So im pretty new with rails, and am working on an API that takes POST requests (from a raspberry-pi) and sets up data in the database.

I have 2 models/schema:

a "Measurement" model. Which simply just contains 2 floats (humidity and temp for now)

and a "Unit" model. Which im not 100% sure how I want to do this, but it will probably just contain an "id" identifying the unit-id in some sort of way.

Anyways, I want measurements to belong to a unit (so I can reference the units for historical value) IE: This raspberry-pi had these temps the past 5 hours..or whatever.

How would I want to arrange this.

I imagine i'd need at the very least `"Measurement"` model to "belong_to" `"Units"` model. Am I forgetting something else? Besides the "has_many" of course for Units. How would I go about creating seed data for this?

I want to eventually be able to have an index page for the "Unit" id that contains it's humidity/temps it's been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `measurements` database record will have a `unit_id` integer field, matching the `id` primary key field of the `units` table.

Rails's ActiveRecord expresses this many-to-one relationship by saying `Unit.has_many :measurements`, and `Measurement.belongs_to :unit`.

From here, take time to just read your tutorials, to soak in all this before trying to code.

Comment: Will I need to explicitly add the "unit_id" field in my migrations? How would I do this if I change my models relationships AFTER the fact (IE: I added the belongs_to/has_many AFTER making the migrations for just the general schema's for units/measurements).

Comment: yes - edit your existing migration file, add the `unit_id`, add its index, then drop and recreate your database. Don't worry about migrations that preserve existing data until you are out of your inception phase. Add the `has_many` and `belongs_to` at the same time. And don't touch your `schema.rb` file, if that's what you mean.